# What is the radius of convergence for $1/[z^2 + 2z + 2]$

Tags: complex-analysis

Complex variables is throwing me off pretty hard. Could be my lack of understanding of some vital calc II as well...either way was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Comment: How do you define the "radius of convergence" of a complex function? It seems you have a infinite series in mind, but you're not telling us that...

Comment: What point is the function centered around? You can expand it around $z=0$, for instance.

Comment: This is not a power series, so it meaningless to ask what the radius of converegence is. Also, we always ask about radius convergence around a center point, and you don't tell us which center to use.

Comment: My professor wrote the book. He gave no center point. I'm assuming we're expanding it around z=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a meromorphic function on the complex plane, you can take the *Taylor expansion* about any point $z=z_0$.  Then you can ask the question: What is the radius of convergence of this Taylor series?  The answer is: Exactly as far as it is from $z_0$ to the nearest singularity.

What still baffles me about this is that you can use this to determine the radii of convergence of *real* Taylor series.  That is, if you have a Taylor series on the real line, this defines a Taylor series centered about that same point considered in $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$, and the radius of convergence *on the real line* is still the distance to the nearest singularity in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}=\frac{1}{(z+1)^2+1}=\frac{1}{(z+1+i)(z+1-i)}=\frac{i}{2}(\frac{1}{z+1+i}-\frac{1}{z+1-i})$ and consider the radius of the two fractions.